# Moving range slider changes another

Tags: javascript, html

I have 5 range sliders as such:

[image]

I'd like to make it so that the sum of the percentages can't exceed 100. So either:

1. Moving a slider up will move the others down (the sliders would have a default state summing to 100)
2. Sliders start at 0, can't move slider past value which would put sum over 100

Is there a simple way to do either of these? I'm having trouble finding much information on this but I know it's commonly done.

Comment: How do you decide which ones to slide down when the sum is too high?

Comment: For simplicity, let's say it will slide down the one below it. (F will slide down A). If the one below is zero, it lower the next one

Comment: If you're using a slider widget, it presumably has a method that allows you to set the current position. So when the sum is `100 + N`, set the next slider to its current value minus `N`. If that would go below zero, take the difference and do it for the slider after it, and so on.